# How to send mail to customer and owner from custom tech support form?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, email, email-templates, email-translation

How to send mail to customer and owner from custom tech support form ?

my Template Content is

```
Name: {{var data.name}}
E-mail: {{var data.email}}
Day: {{var data.day}}
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}
Message: {{var data.message}}
```

i want to use this template and send mail to customer and owner

name cof template is **support**

Comment: Do you want this mail to be sent to both customer and store owner?

Comment: Yes.................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
class Brain_Support_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();     
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function submitAction()
{
  $data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();
  $name=$data['name'];
  $cemail=$data['email'];
  $number=$data['number'];
  $message=$data['message'];
    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->loadDefault('recurring_order_email_template');
  $emailTemplate2 = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->loadDefault('support_thanks_template');

$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['var1'] = $name;
$emailTemplateVariables['var2'] = $cemail;
$emailTemplateVariables['var3'] = $number;
$emailTemplateVariables['var4'] = $message;
$email=Mage::getStoreConfig('support_options/support_data/support_email');
$name=Mage::getStoreConfig('support_options/support_data/support_name');
$emailTemplateVariables['myname'] = $name;
$emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate->setSenderName($name); 
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($email);
$emailTemplate2->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate2->setSenderName($name); 
$emailTemplate2->setSenderEmail($email);
try {

$emailTemplate->send($email, 'vaibbhav', $emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate2->send($cemail, 'vaibbhav', $emailTemplateVariables);
$this->_redirect('/');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Magento Admin Panel` -> `System` -> `Configuration` -> `SALES` -> `Sales Emails` -> `Order` -> `Send Order Email Copy To`

Enter desired email recipients!

Comment: Read this

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49412/how-to-send-dynamic-custom-email-from-magento

Comment: I am Trying to create Tech Support Form

i need to send some data to user just like your request is received and send some to owner